# consuming rest api (like in basecamp) from my .Net application

Tags: .net, api, rest

How can i consume the restful api(like the basecamp)from my .Net applications.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this advertised on Stack Overflow, but haven't tried it yet:

http://restsharp.org/

Comment: Advertised? I think you mean recommended.

Comment: @Oded  No, he means advertised :-)  RESTsharp is one of the open source projects that appears in the advertising sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find an example on how to consume a REST yahoo api:

http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-rest_cs.html

And this link can be useful too:

http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/rest-to-objects-in-c/